# Iterate over an array column in PySpark with map

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In PySpark I have a dataframe composed by two columns:

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| str1      | array_of_str         |
+-----------+----------------------+
| John      | [mango, apple, ...   |
| Tom       | [mango, orange, ...  |
| Matteo    | [apple, banana, ...  |
```

I want to add a column `concat_result` that contains the **concatenation** of each element inside `array_of_str` with the string inside `str1` column.

```
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------------------+
| str1      | array_of_str         | concat_result                    |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------------------+
| John      | [mango, apple, ...   | [mangoJohn, appleJohn, ...       |
| Tom       | [mango, orange, ...  | [mangoTom, orangeTom, ...        |
| Matteo    | [apple, banana, ...  | [appleMatteo, bananaMatteo, ...  |
```

I'm trying to use `map` to iterate over the array:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType

# START EXTRACT OF CODE
ret = (df
  .select(['str1', 'array_of_str'])
  .withColumn('concat_result', F.udf(
     map(lambda x: x + F.col('str1'), F.col('array_of_str')), ArrayType(StringType))
  )
)

return ret
# END EXTRACT OF CODE
```

but I obtain as error:

```
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Column is not iterable - How to iterate over ArrayType()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993439/typeerror-column-is-not-iterable-how-to-iterate-over-arraytype)

Comment: I tried that solution, it does not work. If you can write one that works will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to define a `udf` with 2 arguments - (perhaps unless you're in spark 2.4+)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PySpark dataframe column from list to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108533)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need small tweaks to make this work:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

concat_udf = udf(lambda con_str, arr: [x + con_str for x in arr],
                   ArrayType(StringType()))
ret = df \
  .select(['str1', 'array_of_str']) \
  .withColumn('concat_result', concat_udf(col("str1"), col("array_of_str")))

ret.show()
```

You don't need to use `map`, standard list comprehension is sufficient.

Comment: Only caveat is that this will break if any of the `str1` or `array_of_str` values are `null`. You'd have to add explicit error checking in your `udf`.