# combine the mx value with same name in one line pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i want to covert this value

```
 {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple1.com","type":"mx","value":"20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com"}
    {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple1.com","type":"mx","value":"20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com"}
    {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple1.com","type":"mx","value":"30 aspmx2.googlemail.com"}
    {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple1.com","type":"mx","value":"30 aspmx3.googlemail.com"}
    {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple2.com","type":"mx","value":"20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com"}
    {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple2.com","type":"mx","value":"20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com"}
    {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple2.com","type":"mx","value":"30 aspmx2.googlemail.com"}
    {"timestamp":"1601093713","name":"exmple2.com","type":"mx","value":"30 aspmx3.googlemail.com"}

    test.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

combine the mx value with same name in one line pyspark
the result that i want

```
   { "timestamp":"1601093713", "name":"exmple1.com", "type":"mx", "value":" alt1.aspmx.l.google.com,alt2.aspmx.l.google.com , aspmx2.googlemail.com, aspmx3.googlemail.com" }
   { "timestamp":"1601093713", "name":"exmple2.com", "type":"mx", "value":" alt1.aspmx.l.google.com, alt2.aspmx.l.google.com , aspmx2.googlemail.com, aspmx3.googlemail.com" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `groupBy`, `agg`, and `collect_list` [[docs (external link)]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list). Please not that this will provide with a list of values and not a string. How to do the conversion if needed can be found in [Convert PySpark dataframe column from list to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108331/convert-pyspark-dataframe-column-from-list-to-string).

```py
df_grouped = df.groupby('name').agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('values'))
```

The followup question here would be how you want to handle the other columns. E.g. the timestamp or the type.

Comment: df = spark.read.json("1.json")
df_grouped = df.groupby('name').agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('values')).write \
.save("mxrecord22",format="json")
NameError: name 'F' is not defined

Comment: You will need to Import functions `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'collect_list'

Comment: import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, countDistinct
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000)
df = spark.read.json("1.json")
df = df.groupby('name').agg(df.collect_list('value').alias('values')).write \
.save("mxrecord22",format="json")

Comment: Not `df.collect_list` but `F.collect_list`.